# Displaying MYSQL Data in a Bootstrap Modal before updating it

Tags: html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble displaying data on a bootstrap modal form. I can see the data on the screen and all is fine, but when I click the update button to edit one of the fields there the modal opens and there is no data displayed so when I click save it then saves blank fields bank to the DB.

One of the Values I'm trying to display is:

```
value="<?php echo clean($row['clientTown']); ?>"
```

if i put that anywhere on the page other than the modal, it displays the data.

Any help is appreciated and the code is below.

Code for the Modal

```
<!-- -- Update Media Info Modal -- -->
<div class="modal fade" id="mediainfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="personalInfoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-primary">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Update Media Details</h4>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="clientArea">Hotel Area</label>
                <select name="clientArea" id="clientArea" class="form-control">
                    <?php include 'snippets/countries.php'; ?>
                </select>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="clientMailshot">Mailshot Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="clientMailshot" id="clientMailshot" value="<?php echo clean($row['clientMailshot']); ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="clientChase">Chase Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="clientChase" id="clientChase" value="<?php echo clean($row['clientChase']); ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="clientChased">Second Chase Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="clientChased" id="clientChased" value="<?php echo clean($row['clientChased']); ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="clientAppointment">Appointment Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="clientAppointment" id="clientAppointment" value="<?php echo clean($row['clientAppointment']); ?>">
                </div>

                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="clientBuyer">Media Buyer </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clientBuyer" id="clientBuyer" value="<?php echo clean($row['clientBuyer']); ?>" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="input" name="submit" value="updatemediaInfo" class="btn btn-success btn-icon"><i class="icon-check"></i> Update Info</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding to The DB

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'updatemediaInfo') {
     if($_POST['clientMailshot'] == "") {
        $msgBox = alertBox("Mail Shot is a Required Field.", "<i class='icon-remove-sign'></i>", "danger");
    } else {
        $clientBuyer = encryptIt($_POST['clientBuyer']);

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                            UPDATE
                                clients
                            SET
                                clientBuyer = ?,
                                clientArea = ?,
                                clientMailshot = ?,
                                clientChase = ?,
                                clientChased = ?,
                                clientAppointment = ?
                            WHERE
                                clientId = ?
        ");
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssss',
                            $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clientBuyer']),
                            $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clientArea']),
                            $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clientMailshot']),
                            $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clientChase']),
                            $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clientChased']),
                            $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clientAppointment']),
                            $clientId
        );
        $stmt->execute();
        $msgBox = alertBox("The Client's Personal Info has been updated.", "<i class='icon-check-sign'></i>", "success");
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as button type="input". Change it to button type="submit"

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="updatemediaInfo" class="btn btn-success btn-icon"><i class="icon-check"></i> Update Info</button>
```